# Append string in the beginning and the end of a line containing certain string

Tags: perl

all
I want to know how to append string in the beginning and the end of a line containing certain string using perl?

So for example, my line contains:
%abc %efd;
and I want to append 123 at the beginning of the line and 456 at the end of the line, so it would look like this:

123 %abc %efd 456

8/30/16 UPDATE--------------------------------
So far I have done something like this:

foreach file (`find . -type f`)
perl -ne 's/^\%abc\s+(\S*)/**\%abc $1/; print;' $file > tmp; mv tmp $file
end

foreach file (`find . -type f`)
perl -ne 's/$\%def\;\s+(\S*)/\%def\;**\n $1/; print;' $file > tmp; mv tmp $file
end

so this does pretty well except that when abc and def are not in one string.
for example:

%abc 
something something something 
%def

this would turn out to be 
**%abc 

something something something 

%def;**

which is not what I want.

Thank you

Comment: So are we to consider a single string with many lines manifest by embedded newlines, or is this a multi-line file?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. We strive to help people solve problems in their existing code and learn languages, rather than simply answer one-off questions, the solutions to which can be easily found in 101 tutorials and documentation. The type of question you've posted doesn't leave a lot of room for learning, and doesn't do much to help future learners. It would help us greatly if you could post a more complete example, including what you've tried so far to get it working.

All that being said, there are two main ways to prepend and append to a string in Perl: 1. the [concatenation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators) operator, `.` and 2. string [interpolation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

1. Concatenation

   Use a `.` to join two strings together. You can chain operations together to compose a longer string.

   ```
   my $str = '%abc %efd';
   $str = '123 ' . $str . ' 456';
   say $str; # prints "123 %abc %efd 456" with a trailing newline
   ```
2. Interpolation

   Enclose a string in double quotes to instruct Perl to interpolate (i.e. find and evaluate) any Perl-style variables enclosed within the string.

   ```
   my $str = '%abc %efd';
   $str = "123 $str 456";
   say $str; # prints "123 %abc %efd 456" with a trailing newline
   ```

You'll notice that in both examples we prepended and appended to the existing string. You can also create new variable(s) to hold the result(s) of these operations. Other methods of manipulating and building strings include the `printf` and [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) functions, the [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function, the [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function, and [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), all of which you will encounter as you continue learning Perl.

As far as looking to see if a string contains a certain substring before performing the operation, you can use the [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function or a regular expression:

```
if (index($str, '%abc %efd') >= 0) {
# or...
if ($str =~ /%abc %efd/) {
```

Remember to [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) at the top of your Perl scripts and always (at least while you're learning) declare variables with [`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html). If you're having trouble with the [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) function, you may need to add the statement `use feature 'say';` to the top of your script.

You can find an index of excellent Perl tutorials at [learn.perl.org](https://learn.perl.org/tutorials/). Good luck and have fun!

**UPDATE** Here is (I believe) a complete answer to your revised question:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -i.bak -pe's/^(%abc)\s+(\S*)\s+(%def;)$/**\1 \2 \3**/'
```

This will modify the files in place and create backup files with the extension .bak. Keep in mind that the expression `\S*` will only match non-whitespace characters; if you need to match strings that contain whitespace, you will need to update this expression (something like `.*?` might be workable for you).

Comment: @IanChang You're welcome. Thank you for updating your question. I've posted what I believe is a solution. Let me know if you'd like any further assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In you case, you want to append string when line of file match the certain string, it means match and replace.

Firstly, read each line of your input file.

Secondly, check if it match with the string you want to append string into the beginning and the end.

Then replace the match string by the new string which contain additional beginning string, the match string and additional end string.

```
my $input_file = 'your file name here';
my $search_string = '%abc %efd';
my $add_begin = '123';
my $add_end = '456';
# Read file 
open(my $IN, '<', $input_file) or die "cannot open file $input_file";
# Check each line of file
while (my $row = <$IN>) {
  chomp $row;
  $row =~ s/^($search_string)$/$add_begin $1 $add_end/g;
  print $row."\n";
}
```

Try with input file as below:

```
%abc %efd
asdahsd
234234
%abc
%efd
%abc%efd
```

You will receive the result as we expected:

```
123 %abc %efd 456
asdahsd
234234
%abc
%efd
%abc%efd
```

Modify the code as your requirement and contact me if there's any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `m` modifier to replacing beginning and ending with line by line.

```
 s/^\%abc/123 $&/mg;
 s/\%def$/ 456/mg;
```

> Used together, as /ms, they let the "." match any character whatsoever, while still allowing "^" and "$" to match, respectively, just after and just before newlines within the string. [source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)